# How to store currency symbol for all the countries in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I have a doubt in `mysql` to store data. I don't know how to store all the country currency symbol in `mysql` database. Can any one suggest or give me some idea? Thanks

Comment: You need to give quite a lot more information to get useful answers here. Is it every single currency symbol in the world? Just a subset? What format do you want to store the symbols? HTML character codes? Unicode? An ASCII format (e.g. USD, GBP, etc)? All of the above?

Comment: Thank you  DaveyDaveDave I want to store currency symbols not character set ,want to stored in mysql database

Answer (score -1):

You need to store these HTML codes for countries. Please check the link you will find out the codes.

Save them as a separate column.

http://character-code.com/currency-html-codes.php

Comment: I don't think this really answers the original question, especially as he's now clarified that he doesn't want to store the HTML codes.